# Silverlight Tooltip Style ContentPresenter TextWrapping

Tags: silverlight, styles, tooltip, word-wrap, contentpresenter

I want to create a Silverlight Tooltip Style but I don't want to use a textblock because the tooltip content might be an image or something else. So I'm using a ContentPresenter. My problem is how to set MaxWidth and force TextWrapping when content is text. This is what I have so far:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit">

    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.8"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10,0,-5" Width="Auto">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="16" ShadowDepth="8" Direction="-45" Color="Black" Opacity="0.6"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this:
Create 2 Tooltip styles - one for text and another for everything else, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TooltipStyleForText" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10,0,-5" Width="Auto">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="16" ShadowDepth="8" Direction="-45" Color="Black" Opacity="0.6"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TooltipStyleForOtherStuffThanText" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10,0,-5" Width="Auto">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="16" ShadowDepth="8" Direction="-45" Color="Black" Opacity="0.6"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and than when we use a TextBlock, call it's ToolTip style like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="something">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource TooltipStyleForText}">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

This might not be the best solution because we have two styles so we need to specify write several lines for a simple TextBlock.
I hope someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

We needed to do the same thing and tried a few approaches before setting on the following solution. The problem is that when the ToolTip.Content is a string you need to show the tooltip using a TextBlock. When ToolTip.Content is not a string you need to use a ContentPresenter. So we ended up defining a ControlTemplate that has both, and we show/hide the appropriate one based on the type of ToolTip.Content. This approach is applied to all ToolTips in the application:

The following converter class helps out with this:

```
public class TooltipContentVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Visibility VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsAString { get; set; }
    public Visibility VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsNotAString { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var toolTip = value as ToolTip;
        if (toolTip != null && toolTip.Content is string)
        {
            return VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsAString;
        }

        return VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsNotAString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your App.xaml you define the following.

```
<Converter:TooltipContentVisibilityConverter VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsAString="Visible" VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsNotAString="Collapsed" x:Key="tooltipStringContentVisibilityConverter" />
<Converter:TooltipContentVisibilityConverter VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsAString="Collapsed" VisibilityWhenToolTipContentIsNotAString="Visible" x:Key="tooltipNonStringContentVisibilityConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="300" 
                       Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip},Converter={StaticResource tooltipStringContentVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                              Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip},Converter={StaticResource tooltipNonStringContentVisibilityConverter}}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
    </Style>
```

It seems like a bit of an awkward way to have to solve this problem, but it does work and we haven't found a better solution yet.